# Unable to remove rows from a tibble with a completely missing parameter

Tags: r

I'm piping some ndjson with a stream (using jsonlite) and some rows of the ndjson are completely missing a variable parameter. I can't work out how to filter out these rows earlier.
To clarify, this is NOT a variable present but with a missing value or an N/A - it is a completely missing variable, so my

```
select(var1, var2,..)
```

statement crashes out if a row is missing .

I'm happy to throuw away the whole record if it's missing one of my parameters of interest.

Any suggestion would be most welcome. Google keeps only giving me hits on dealing with missing values.

Comment: Having some sample data would help.  But perhaps na.omit(select(var1, var2,...)) or select(var1,var2,...) %>% na.omit() if you're using pipes?

Comment: Check if the data frame has a name that corresponds to the variable or not.

Comment: many thanks, I'll try those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr::select` drops an error if a column/variable (not rows/observations) is missing from the tibble/df:

```
> select(dplyr::starwars, "name", "height", "dune")
Error in `select()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `dune` doesn't exist.
```

If you're unsure about missing columns, try the selection-helper `dplyr::any_of`:

```
> select(dplyr::starwars, any_of(c("name", "height", "dune")))
# A tibble: 87 × 2
   name               height
   <chr>               <int>
 1 Luke Skywalker        172
 2 C-3PO                 167
 3 R2-D2                  96
 4 Darth Vader           202
 5 Leia Organa           150
 6 Owen Lars             178
 7 Beru Whitesun Lars    165
 8 R5-D4                  97
 9 Biggs Darklighter     183
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        182
# ℹ 77 more rows
```